How can these cream milk fat percentages be correct?
Recently I was at a conference at which coffee was served. On the coffee table there was a carton of Neilson brand cream with the following information listed on top: "5% M.F. dairy creamer". (Note: "M.F." stands for milk fat here).
It then goes on to advertise the following about itself: "Light - 33% less milk fat than our Neilson 10% M.F. cream".
In a conference full of mathematicians, none of us were able to figure out how these numbers possibly made sense. (5% is half (50%) of 10%, not 33%). Surely the text should read "50% less milk fat".
Furthermore, if the brand is trying to get across that this product has less milk fat than the other, surely from an advertising perspective they would want to lean into the 50% tagline, and describe it as healthily as possible.
My question is: How can these numbers possibly make sense, and is there something from a food/dairy perspective that I might be missing here?


Only thing I can imagine is if there’s set % values they can/do round to. 33% less than 9% is 6%. I know some nutrition fact stuff gets real weird with what counts as “0” and how you get percentages. Have seen 0g added sugar labeled as “1% DV” before … and 1g carbohydrate as “0% DV” for the same item

Marketing department is not made of Mathematicians, thinks "math is hard" and also thinks they don't need no mathematicians to keep them honest (well, it's the marketing department, so "honest" is not exactly likely, is it?)

I was pondering whether there may be any other fat that is not milk fat in either of these products but all three references clearly state milk fat.

can you compare the serving sizes? they may consider a serving of the 5% milk fat to be larger than a serving of the 10%?

My guess is the ratio has been computed from rounded values.


The Neilson 5% dairy creamer nutrition facts sheet says there is 1g of fat per tablespoon (15ml):




The Neilson half and half cream (a.k.a 10% cream) nutrition facts sheet says there is 1.5g of fat per tablespoon:




1g fat is 33% less fat than 1.5g fat. QED.
On the other hand, the calories ratio is consistent, jumping from 10 (5% MF) to 20 (10% MF).

That looks like the correct answer. Calories look rounded up though, it seems the correct reduction would be from 20cal to 17cal not to 10cal according to this calculator https://www.omnicalculator.com/conversion/grams-to-calories

They cannot be correct. LOL. I mistakenly thought it could be the percentage of a reconstructed milk/cream recipe, but @Stephie correctly pointed out I was not making sense. Percent fat (for milk or cream) is by legal definition the percentage of butterfat by weight of the milk product in both Canada and the United States. Even fudging with rounding (9.5% down to 5.4%), it is no where near just a 33% reduction. It just has to be a mistake.
